# SSH connection issue although remote site is pingable

Tags: linux

I can ping IP address of a node, but cannot ssh into. I have checked firewall settings, and there is no problem on that end. Still we get the connections denied error while truing to ssh the IP address.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases the most probable cause is that the ssh daemon doesn't run on the remote side. You need to start it with the command `/etc/init.d/ssh start`. If were much better if you gave, which linux distro are you using.

It is also possible that the connecting IP or port is somehow added to the deny rules, also there is a firewall problem. You can test this, if you temporary turn off your firewall - if there is the problem, you will know what to do.

In such reports it is also very good if you copy-paste the relevant error messages, it can help a lot.

Comment: The OP has stated they get "connections denied" error. As you say, possibly not started ssh daemon. The connecting IP could also have been accidentally added to a deny list on the remote server.

Comment: @BigChris Yes, it is also possible. I extended my answer.